# MIMETYPE returning null in CursorLoader

Tags: android, mime-types, android-cursorloader

I have a Listfragment that has a cursoradapter for inflating row items. I am using android contact provider for inflating list items. I am able to add my custom mimetype to the contacts by ContactProviderOperation.The value is inserted as expected. But when i am trying to use my custom mimetype as SELECTION parameter for returning a cursorloader it is not working. Below is my code:

```
return new CursorLoader(getContext(), Data.CONTENT_URI, new String[]{Data.CONTACT_ID,Data.DATA1}, Data.MIMETYPE+"= ?", new String{"vnd.cursor.item/mimetype"}, null)
```

I added breakpoint for the SELECTION. Seems like cursorloader is not accepting my MIMETYPE for the selection parameter.Please help me on this.

Below is the code to add data:

`ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(Data.CONTENT_URI)
                        .withSelection(Data.CONTACT_ID+"= ?"+Data.MIMETYPE+"= ?", new String[]{contactId,"vnd.cursor.item/mimetype"})
                        .withValue(Data.DATA1, 0).build());
            getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);`

Comment: have you read: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html , section "Custom data rows" ?

Comment: @pskink yes i have read it. I have followed the same in my code. Cant get where i am going wrong though...is there something wrong with the return statement??

Comment: whats your contacts.xml like?

Comment: @pskink u mean xml file for list items?? It has a quickContactBadge,a name and a phone number text fields. Just like android phone book.

Comment: read the above link again, ^F contacts.xml

Comment: @pskink i dont want my data to be displayed in contacts application's UI. I just want to retrieve my custom data to use in my application.

Comment: so how do you create your ContentProviderOperation ? post your code

Comment: try: `ContentProviderOperation.Builder b = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI); b.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, raw_contact_id);
        b.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, your_mime_type);`